# Is there a shortcut key or an extension that can active specific Google Chrome devtool panel?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

This is a Chrome devtool, there are some panels in it... "Network", "Console","Sources","Elements",

Is there any shortcut key or extension that can active specific panel by keyboard, rather than click?

EDIT: command + [(]) will move to next/prev panel, not active specific panel, I want to open Source panel(or other panel) directly

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

You can find the shortcuts from the Settings panel in developer tools

[image]

There doesn't appear to be a key combination to navigate to a specific panel.

Comment: This will  select the next or prev panel, not specific panel